# Jenkins lists Git Changes on build push changes to gitlab as tag release notes

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, changelog

Is it possible for a Jenkins Build to a master branch to push the listed changes in Jenkins back to GitLab, under the Tagged Release Notes ?

Is there a plug in for this

I'm using the Jenkinsfile declarative script, this is for a pipeline, so the options is available in the UI as post-action builds.

Any advise or help would be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is the [git-changelog-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin), which can help.
If it is the case of using shell script, try this [link](https://github.com/titanium-codes/bump.sh).